# Is the reactivity of Benzene with an -N(R)₃⁺ group greater than its reactivity with an -NH₃⁺ group?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

Both are m-directors, and Electron Withdrawing groups, but which one is more reactive? At first sight, one might think clearly $\ce{-N(R)_3^+}$ is more reactive, but when you factor in that $\ce R$ is actually an o,p-director, hence activator, then I think $\ce{-N(R)_3^+}$ is indeed stronger than $\ce{ NH_3^+}$. I can't seem to find any verification on the internet for this.

Comment: R being an o-p director doesn't make NR3 a o-p director.

Comment: @ManishEarth and David, Isn't $\ce{NR3}$ in $\ce{ph-NR2}$ o-p directing? If I am not wrong, what is deactivating (and probably m-directing) is an $\ce{NR4^+}$ group as in $\ce{Ph-NR3^+}$? In the same way, Aniline has a o-p directing $-\ce{NH2}$ group but $\ce{NH3^+}$ attached to phenyl is deactivating (not sure if m-directing). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @SatwikPasani Yeah, I assumed he's talking about $\ce{Ph-NH3^+}$ and $\ce{Ph-NR3^+}$ which are both meta (rather strong, too). David, is this interpretation correct? Or are you asking about $\ce{Ph-NH2}$ vs $\ce{Ph-NR2}$

Comment: @ManishEarth correct

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{Ph-NR_3^+}$  is likely weaker than $\ce{Ph-NH_3^+}$ because the mechanism of deactivation is based on the amount of positive charge localized on the Nitrogen:  Alkylgroups will stabilized the positive charge through sigma donation.

That being said, the difference will be small.  Additionally, there are deprotonation side-reactions to consider for anilium ($\ce{Ph-NH_3^+}$) ions, which may compromise any discussion of deactivation.